# Bigtable authentication in java

Tags: java, authentication, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am looking for an alternative way to authenticate in Bigable.
Default approach involves the environment variable, which concerns me.

I found [`GoogleCredential`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) class. It can read json key file with fromStream, but how to use the new instance of `GoogleCredential`.
There is no method to `setApplicationDefault()`. I need override it somehow.

HBase code doesn't know anything about `GoogleCredential`.

Comment: CBT Code does know about credentials.  Don't set config variables.  We use applicationDefault as our primary method of getting credentials (i.e. the credentials set via gcloud auth commands).

See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-hbase/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BigtableOptionsFactory.java#L212 and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-client-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/config/CredentialFactory.java#L99

Comment: The quick start forces you to use the environment variable, but I have a Pull Request to remove that check: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/pull/116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT 12/6/2016

Default Auth now requires `gcloud auth application-default login` to use your user account for API calls.  You can also do:

`$ gcloud iam service-accounts create my-account
        $ gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json
          --iam-account=my-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        $ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=key.json
        $ ./my_applicaiton.sh`

#### Old Text

For most things, the Default Auth is enough.  If you've done **`gcloud init`** or it's predecessor `gcloud auth login` it should generally be enough.  (EDIT - `gcloud beta auth application-default login` is now used for API access).
There are some special circumstances where it won't be, such as if you are running locally inside a Docker container.  Then your Default Auth won't have been setup correctly and you need to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

For completeness, it is also possible to set the `google.bigtable.auth.json.keyfile` key in your `hbase-site.xml` file if you are doing some cross project activities, but that should be very rare.

Comment: hbase-site.xml attribute is right what I looked for. Its value is feed right to FileInputStream so a relative path can be used.